# Recursive function - proof by induction

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion, induction

Let $\Sigma$ denote an alphabet and $[ \Sigma ]$ set of lists.

I've encountered the following function:

$f([])=[]$ (empty list)

$f([x])=[x]$, for $x \in \Sigma$

$f(x:L)=f(L)$, for $x \in \Sigma$ and $L \in [ \Sigma ]$

The function is supposed to return a tail for nonempty list. That is:

$f([x_1,x_2,...,x_n])=[x_n]$

How would you understand the ":" operator in the definition?

Inductive proof should be possible for showing that such a "tail function" is indeed working.

Comment: Also posted at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420812/recursive-function-proof-by-induction)  and [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433108/inductive-proof-for-recursive-function) within a few hours. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without wasting anybody's time. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may flag to request migration.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a template match, meaning if you have some list $L = [x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$, then $L = x:L'$ where $L' = [x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n]$.

So you can imagine what that definition is saying is that $f(x:L)$ is equivalent to operating on the rest of the list, i.e. $L$ in this case, hence $f(L)$.

Induction follows pretty easily because once you've shown for a list of length $n$, to show $n+1$, you just use the function definition, which peels off the first element, and you immediately have a list of $n$, which is true by the inductive hypothesis.

Note that there are also notations such as

- $L:y$ : $y$ is the last element
- $x:L:y$ : $x$ is the head, $y$ is the tail